# Can you create a modal in anychart from the reaction to a single event on the chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph, anychart

I'm working with Network Graph and what I'm trying to do is when a node is selected in the graph it can show a specific modal for that single node, is this possible?

Comment: Why are you giving task to others? This platform is used to raise a question and to get your desired answer. That question must show some effort of research too. This is not a place to submit your homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no exact modal pop-ups in AnyChart, but you can use a different approach.
It is possible to get [attributes from a node you clicked](https://playground.anychart.com/7fOE48h1/1) with an [event listener](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.core.Base#listen) and use them as you wish in your application, including your own custom modal windows.

```
let clickedNode = "Click node to change ";
  
  chart.listen('click', function(e) {
    var tag = e.domTarget.tag;
    if (tag.type == "node") {
   
      if (tag.type === 'node') {    
        clickedNode = tag.id
        alert("You just click node: " + clickedNode)
        chart.title("Last clicked node: " + clickedNode)
      }
    }
  });
```